# MATLAB figure text colour changing upon save

Tags: matlab

I am trying to save a figure which contains text in white. I changed the text colour by the following code:

```
  txt = text(x + window_breadth,y - 2,personID);
  set(txt, 'Color','w','FontSize',font_size);
```

When I show the figure in MATLAB, the text colour changes to white as it should. However, when I try to save it in a directory as follows:

```
fullFileName = sprintf('/Video 1/Before&After_frame_%d.png', curr_frame);
saveas(beforeANDafter_figure, fullFileName);
```

The text colour changes back to black. Anyone knows why this is happening please?